Attention Mechanism: Why don't we just use a simple dot product instead of the Q, K, V matrices?
I am currently learning about Transformers by reading Richard Turner's paper "An Introduction to Transformers". On page 3 of the paper he gave a "naive" approach to build the attention matrix by a simple dot product of the input vector $X$ (then passing through a softmax function) - given input vector $X$ (a $D \times N$ matrix) we can calculate the $n, n'$-th entry of the attention matrix $A$ as:
$$A_{n,n'} = \frac{\exp( \textbf{x}_n^\top  \textbf{x}_{n'})}{\sum_{n''=1}^N \exp(\textbf{x}_{n''}^\top \textbf{x}_{n'})}$$
Written in matrix form it would be:
$$A = \text{softmax}(X^{\top}X)$$
Where $\text{softmax}(M)$ means to apply the regular softmax function to each column of the matrix $M$.
He later on explained that this approach "entangles information about the similarity between locations in the sequence with the content of the sequence itself", and thus improving it by applying a linear transformation $U$ to the vector $\textbf{x}_n$:
$$A_{n,n'} = \frac{\exp( \textbf{x}_n^\top U^\top U \textbf{x}_{n'})}{\sum_{n''=1}^N \exp(\textbf{x}_{n''}^\top U^\top U \textbf{x}_{n'})}$$
or
$$A = \text{softmax}(X^\top U^\top UX)$$
And later, he again improving it further by using two separate linear transformations $U_k$ and $U_q$, since "the numerator
in this construction is symmetric and this could be a disadvantage":
$$A_{n,n'} = \frac{\exp \left( \textbf{x}_n^\top U_{\textbf{k}}^\top U_{\textbf{q}}^{} \textbf{x}_{n'} \right)}{\sum_{n''=1}^N \exp \left(\textbf{x}_{n''}^\top U_{\textbf{k}}^\top U_{\textbf{q}}^{} \textbf{x}_{n'}\right)}$$
or
$$ A = \text{softmax}(X^\top U_k^\top U_qX)$$
My problem is that the exact disadvantage of the two approaches above and the exact improvements each new approach provides isn't explained very clearly in the paper. Is it possible for anyone to offer a more detailed (both intuitively and mathematically) explanation on the disadivantage of each of the naive approaches and how the improvement would help?
